# Send duplicate message to bridge

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Can I prevent duplicate message sent to bridge?
I've set the duplicate flag from client, but the broker still send new message with dup = 0.

The message m870 is sent twice, because the first time PUBACK is not received by client (maybe some internet broke in the middle). Client re-deliever m870 with dup = 1, but server still send the message to broker with dup = 0. (That makes other broker connects to bridge thought this message is new, and publish to all the subscribed clients).

```
1488965834: Received PUBLISH from client (d0, q1, r0, m870, 'test/topic', ... (10 bytes))
1488965834: Sending PUBACK to client (Mid: 870)
1488965834: Sending PUBLISH to bridge (d0, q1, r0, m58118, 'B/test/topic', ... (10 bytes))
1488965834: Received PUBACK from bridge (Mid: 58118)
1488965838: Received PUBLISH from client (d1, q1, r0, m870, 'test/topic', ... (10 bytes))
1488965838: Sending PUBACK to client (Mid: 870)
1488965838: Sending PUBLISH to bridge (d0, q1, r0, m58121, 'B/test/topic', ... (10 bytes))
1488965838: Received PUBACK from bridge (Mid: 58121)
```

This question is also post to [mosquitto/issues/398](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/398)

Comment: Please don't cross post things to multiple places, it fragments responses

Comment: Also git issues are normally for defects (actual problems with the code) not general questions, there is a Mosquitto developers mailing list that would be more appropriate for these questions.

Comment: @hardillb, thanks for reply. OK, I understand, sorry for that. I have already subscribe to the mailing list but got no respond, and I guess the mailing list is not working? Have you got mail from the mailing list recently?

Comment: Because for that, I don't know where to post my question, so I post to stackoverflow, and yesterday I found there github issue, and post there too. I don't know where to reach the guys who develop on this :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are miss understanding the dup flag.

This flag is set by the a client when it is re-delivering a QOS 1/2 message to the broker that didn't confirm arrival of the original version message sent.

It is also set by the broker when doing the same to a client.

Each of these transactions is separate, setting it on the publishing client for the first time a message is sent will not achieve anything.

Details in the spec here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349261

Comment: Thanks @hardillb, But that situation happened when my client didn't receive PUBACK from server (maybe some internet broke in the middle), so resend the PUBLISH to server with dup = 1. I have sent m870 twice, first time is dup = 0 and second time is dup =1.

Comment: I've update the original post for more detail descriptions.